# How to make this setState function non recursive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and is in very early stages. I was trying to add a object to an array from another component to a different component. I was able to achieve this using props but now when I try to set it in this.state setState calls the render function again thus triggering this function again. I was able to solve this problem using a button but I don't want to do it this way. Is there some better way to do this?

```
getData() {
    if (this.props.data.employeeData !== undefined) {
        if (this.props.isNewEmployee === "true") {
            this.setState({
                isNewEmployee: "true",
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (this.state.isNewEmployee === "true") {
                    console.log(this.props.data.employeeData.firstName);
                    var joined = this.state.EmployeesList.concat(this.props.data.employeeData);
                    this.setState({
                        EmployeesList: joined,
                        isNewEmployee: "false",
                    })
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Don't know what's happening anymore");
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        else {
            console.log("No new employee added");
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.getData()}
            {this.renderTable()}
            {this.renderFloatingActionButton()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What's the desired behavior? You want to render something when the component is first mounted, then 100 milliseconds later have it render something else?

Comment: You are calling `this.getData()`, which sets the state that inturn calls `render` again. You need to move the logic to one of the life cycle methods `componentWillReceiveProps`, if you expect the component to receive new props. And `componentDidMount` when the component gets mounted initially.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent of the `props` is to add the new data to the table I would be doing something in these lines.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.data.employeeData && nextProps.isNewEmployee !== this.props.isNewEmployee) {
      console.log(this.props.data.employeeData.firstName);
      var joined = this.state.EmployeesList.concat(this.props.data.employeeData);
      this.setState({
        EmployeesList: joined,
        isNewEmployee: "false",
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No new employee added");
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderTable()}
            {this.renderFloatingActionButton()}
        </div>
    )
}
```